# Deleting Users in Windows 10 using Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-10, windows-server-2012

My department wants a script to be run in Windows Powershell on our server that will remove users if their account is locked or hasn't been logged into for a long time. We started with using a C# script to pull from an excel sheet that shows when the last logins were, locked or unlocked, and users' names. How can I go about removing users from our server using a script?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. For any specific problem you are having please include a [mcve]. Please also read [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask). Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic). Also, be sure to take the [tour] (you get a badge!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to delete it with powershell, not C#, right? If that's the case, The thing you're looking is the [`Remove-LocalUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/remove-localuser?view=powershell-5.1)command.

`Remove-LocalUser -Name "NAME OF USER"`

**EDIT**

If you have AD(Active Directory) users, it is almost the same:
`Remove-ADUser -Identity NAMEOFUSER`

I don't know how to delete any other kinds of users. Sorry!

Comment: Why do you assume the question is about removing **Local** users?

Comment: I don't know. I just did. I don't know how to delete any other kind. I just thought it was a local user so I posted what I knew.

Comment: All of the users are on our server so they can log into any PC on the network. We tried the Remove-LocalUser command on our server and it didn't recognize the command. If it helps, the VM our server is on is Windows Server 2012.

Comment: I know why! Looks like the powershell version is not 5.1. Though, if you can, would you mind running `Get-Host | Select-Object Version` to see the version? If it is lower than 5.1, it will not work. Sorry!

Comment: Removing ADUser worked. The powershell version on the server is 4.0 though. Thanks for the help!